# Running all possible additive combinations of a linear model and averaging the coefficients

Tags: r, regression, p-value, regression-coefficients

I have nine predictor variables and one response and when I run a linear model in R I'm getting negative coefficients and non-significant p-vales for essentially all the estimates. I've examined the predicted vs observed plot and the model seems to fit well but I'm really more interested in interpreting the coefficients but I'm not sure if I can trust the estimates and negative values don't make sense in a real world context. So I thought that maybe running all possible model combination and averaging the coefficients together might get me better estimates? Is this something that make sense to do?

```
Call:
lm(formula = sales ~ t + n + p + r + s + d + db + r + a)

Coefficients:
              Estimate Std. Error t value Pr(>|t|)    
(Intercept)  2.867e+06  1.429e+06   2.006   0.0554 .  
t            1.033e+06  6.426e+04  16.070 5.09e-15 ***
n            8.866e-01  3.184e+00   0.278   0.7829    
p           -5.045e+00  1.942e+01  -0.260   0.7971    
rd           3.442e+01  2.582e+01   1.333   0.1941    
s           -7.799e+01  1.288e+02  -0.606   0.5500    
d           -9.826e+01  5.992e+01  -1.640   0.1131    
db           6.301e+01  3.468e+01   1.817   0.0808 .  
r            1.558e+01  7.469e+01   0.209   0.8364    
a           -5.466e+00  2.229e+01  -0.245   0.8082  

Residual standard error: 2675000 on 26 degrees of freedom
Multiple R-squared:  0.9559,    Adjusted R-squared:  0.9407 
F-statistic: 62.65 on 9 and 26 DF,  p-value: 2.421e-15
```

Without t:

```
Call:
lm(formula = sales ~ n + p + r + s + d + db + r + a)


Coefficients:
              Estimate Std. Error t value Pr(>|t|)  
(Intercept)  5.265e+06  4.612e+06   1.142   0.2637  
n            2.223e+01  9.390e+00   2.368   0.0253 *
p            3.357e+01  6.251e+01   0.537   0.5956  
rd           6.147e+01  8.359e+01   0.735   0.4685  
s            5.445e+02  3.984e+02   1.366   0.1831  
d            2.591e+01  1.928e+02   0.134   0.8941  
db          -1.120e+02  1.068e+02  -1.048   0.3039  
r            4.639e+02  2.248e+02   2.064   0.0488 *
a          4.808e+00  7.228e+01   0.067   0.9475  


Residual standard error: 8679000 on 27 degrees of freedom
Multiple R-squared:  0.5181,    Adjusted R-squared:  0.3754 
F-statistic: 3.629 on 8 and 27 DF,  p-value: 0.005482
```

Comment: It will produce a fit that is the average of all $2^{10}-1=1023$ fits that can be made. This guarantees it will be worse than many possible fits, so why use it?

Comment: Ok yeah just trying to think of how to fix this model so I have good estimates and can interpret the coefficients

Comment: There is a somewhat famous paper in economics arguing that something like what you are doing can be thought of as approximating a Bayesian approach to model selection.  I'm too ignorant of Baeyesian statistics to have an opinion on whether they are right or not.  Here's the link:  http://www.nber.org/papers/w7750

Comment: I must say I do not follow the logic in the paper - it basically says: we cannot choose priors for multiple models, so we could use uninformative priors, but they are like frequentionist estimates, so we use frequentionist estimates, average them and call it Bayesian... This sounds fancy but does not convince me at all.

Comment: Ha Dilbert comic is very funny

Comment: @Bill That is a very interesting paper.  It has almost an Empirical Bayes feel to it: a *weighted* average of models is taken with the weights determined by the individual likelihoods together with a prior distribution over the number of variables to include.  This will favor good-fitting models having nearly that number of variables.  These two innovations--likelihood-based weighting and a somewhat informative prior--overcome my initial objections to the approach.  They begin to sound in spirit almost like bagging and boosting procedures.

Comment: I suggest googling for "Variable selection" or "feature selection" or just going to chapter 10 of ftp://cran.r-project.org/pub/R/doc/contrib/Faraway-PRA.pdf . Reading about colinearity (in the same source) can be useful, too. I'm afraid you are trying to invent the wheel while faced with a quite common problem.

Answer (score 1):

What exactly does your model try to predict?

What is its R² value?

Averaging the coefficients is not a valid idea, as you would essentially introduce omitted variable bias into each noncomplete model, with unpredictable results for the averaged model.

You could, however, run various tests for joint significance of several variables.

Comment: Hmmm, ok I added the call and R^2 the model is predicting sales and the predictors are monthly spend for 3 years

Comment: You have a serious case of multicollinearity/overfitting. That explains both the nonsensical signs and the strange significance values. In this case, you have basically two options: either add more observations or reduce the number of variables.

Comment: Well the t variable that is trend accounts for most of the R^2, which is just a number form 1:36 for three years of monthly data

Comment: Yeah - economically, both the constant and the trend are in the order of magnitude of millions, while your other variables have coeffcients on or below the single dollar level - thus, they do not really offer much explanatory power, but the whole model fits really well because you have many degrees of freedom for few variables. Thus, you should probably try to work with a much simpler model first.

Comment: Ok I see, what if my goal is just to explain how those variable effect sales I can't really eliminate them?

Comment: With your given number of observations you can't really interpret single coefficients in a meaningful way, i'm afraid.

Comment: Is it an error that a variable called r is used twice in the model?

Comment: Interesting, perhaps this is why these type of models run with weekly data

Comment: That may very well be the reason, yes.

Comment: Oh no not an error I just edited the names I edited one to be rd. Does it make sense to regress many different spend variables against sales in this way to understand the contribution of those variables to sales? Are there better techniques for that type of question?